# I am not able to filter by Current date in excel column (AA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to filter column (AA) Based on current date,column AA contains dates and its data type also date
please help me
[I am attching screenshot of column AA][1]
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
Dim dDate As Date
dDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
MsgBox (dDate)

Dim j As Integer
Dim MyArr(16) As String

For j = 2 To 16
MyArr(j) = Cells(j, 29).Value
Next
Dim nFirst As Long, nLast As Long, i As Long
Dim item As String

```
Dim arrTemp() As String
Dim Coll As New Collection

'Get First and Last Array Positions
nFirst = LBound(MyArr)
nLast = UBound(MyArr)
ReDim arrTemp(nFirst To nLast)

'Convert Array to String
For i = nFirst To nLast
    arrTemp(i) = CStr(MyArr(i))
Next i

'Populate Temporary Collection
On Error Resume Next
For i = nFirst To nLast
    Coll.Add arrTemp(i), arrTemp(i)
Next i
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

'Resize Array
nLast = Coll.count + nFirst - 1
ReDim arrTemp(nFirst To nLast)

'Populate Array
For i = nFirst To nLast
    arrTemp(i) = Coll(i - nFirst + 1)
Next i
For i = 1 To nLast
MsgBox (arrTemp(i))
Selection.AutoFilter
MsgBox (Cells(2, 27).Value)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AN$16").AutoFilter Field:=27, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, dDate)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AN$16").AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:= _
    arrTemp(i)
Selection.Copy
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:N").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:N").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:E").Select
Range("E1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("E:P").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1:C1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
count = count + 1
Next
```

End Sub

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX8zt.png
```

Comment: This: `dDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")` makes no sense. Should be: `dDate = Date`. A date value carries no format.

Comment: What in the world is all that code for?  It seems you are doing more than just filtering dates from a column. Please edit your question to present the code segment that is causing a problem, as well as a data sample that demonstrates the problem. Might help to read the HELP topic about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).